# Prove $-a\le b\le a$ if $|b|\le a$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I've tried it as follows:

> Suppose $|b|\le a.$ $|b|$ is either $b$ or $-b$. That is, $$b\le a\quad\text{or}\quad-b\le a.$$ The latter can be rewritten as $-a\le b.$

Then, **combining $b\le a$ and $-a\le b$ would give me $\mathbb{R}$**, since we used *or* in the first place. How can I fix my proof?

Comment: Actually, $|b|\le a$ is equivalent to $b\leq a$ _and_ $-b\leq a$, not just "or".

Comment: @Arthur I'm just focusing on this direction. However, thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you start your proof over.

First, prove that $a\geq 0$ (this will be useful later).

Second, notice that you really need to prove **two** inequalities: the inequality $-a\leq b$ and the inequality $b\leq a$.

Then, split the proof into three cases:

- $b>0$: if $b>0$, then $|b| = b$, so the inequality $|b|\leq a$ becomes $b\leq a$, so the second inequality clearly holds. To prove $-a\leq b$, use the fact that $a\geq 0$.
- $b<0$: Similar as above:
- $b=0$: even easier.

Comment: By the first step, you actually meant to say $|b|\ge 0$? That was also on the separate theorem (which can be trivially proved.) I think your approach is probably what the author wants.

Comment: @Il-seobBae No, I mean $a\geq 0$. You need this later (in my first point, I say "use the fact that $a\geq 0$".

Comment: I mean, $|b|\ge 0$ leads to the fact $a\ge |b|\ge 0.$

Comment: @Il-seobBae You probably mean $0\leq |b|\leq a$, right?

Comment: Yes. That actually boils down to $a\ge 0$.

Comment: @Il-seobBae Indeed. Now you can continue with the split into cases.

Answer (score 0):

$|b|$ it's the distance between $b$ on the $x$-axis and the origin.

Thus, for $a\geq0$ we get $-a\leq b\leq a$ and for $a<0$ we get $\oslash$.

Comment: I sort of expected an algebraic reasoning, but thanks.